# Slack API: How to determine which human user owns a Legacy API token

Tags: slack, slack-api

When using a [legacy token](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) in slack I want to determine which user account owns this application.  The information is not directly in the bot.info:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "bot": {
    "id": "foobar",
    "deleted": false,
    "name": "Slack API Tester",
    "updated": 123456789,
    "app_id": "A123"
  }
}
```

Could I use the bot.id or bot.app_id objects to find who owns this application? If so which api call would I use.

Answer (score 1):

To determine which user owns any token (incl. legacy token) just call the [`auth.test`](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) endpoint with that token. You will get the user ID and name of the token owner.

Example response from documentation:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "url": "https://subarachnoid.slack.com/",
    "team": "Subarachnoid Workspace",
    "user": "grace",
    "team_id": "T12345678",
    "user_id": "W12345678"
}
```

If you need more info about the user you can call [users.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) for that user with his ID. Since you are using a legacy token you will have the necessary permissions.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the only method I have found that works.  Unfortunately, it means you need the api token accessible.  In my environment, I will have access to the bot id of messages send from legacy tokens, but I will not have the actual legacy token.